# WCF Streamed errror (maximum message size quota)

Tags: wcf

I have WCF service library with this config:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
   <binding name="httpLargeMessageStream" 
        maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"      
        messageEncoding="Mtom" transferMode="Streamed" />
</basicHttpBinding>

<netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="tcpLargeMessageStream" transferMode="Streamed" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
</netTcpBinding>
```

and from client side if I send request for upload file, then all work fine

```
public void UploadFile(FileUploadMessage request)
{
   try
   {
      // Gets absolute local storing path 
      string localPath = Path.Combine(basePath, request.UploadMetadata.StoringPath);

      // Create folders in they don't exist
      FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(localPath);
      file.Directory.Create();

      // Get document path on server
      string serverFileName = Path.Combine(localPath, request.UploadMetadata.HashFileName);

      // Create a new temp document 
      using (FileStream outfile = new FileStream(serverFileName, FileMode.Create))
      {
         // Read buffer
         const int bufferSize = 65536;

         // Output buffer 
         Byte[] buffer = new Byte[bufferSize];
         int bytesRead;

         // Write bytes from source into local file
         while ((bytesRead = request.FileByteStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
         {
            outfile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
         }
      }
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
      throw new FaultException<IOException>(e);
   }
}
```

but for download request I already got error:

> The maximum message size quota for
>   incoming messages (65536) has been
>   exceeded. To increase the quota, use
>   the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on
>   the appropriate binding element.

```
public FileDownloadReturnMessage DownloadFile(FileDownloadMessage request)
{
   try
   {
      controlServerAdress = "http://localhost:8080/ControlServer/";

      EndpointAddress basicBinding = new EndpointAddress(controlServerAdress + "TokenService/basic");
      tokenService = new TokenServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_ITokenService", basicBinding);

      // Get file token form control server
      ComDocFile file = tokenService.ResolveToken(request.DownloadMetadata.Token);

      // If exist file for token
      if (file != null)
      {
         // Get document path on server
         string serverFileName = Path.Combine(basePath, file.FilePath, file.FileName);

         // Set fileName 
         request.DownloadMetadata.FileName = file.FileName;

         // Return file stream
         return new FileDownloadReturnMessage(new FileStream(serverFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), new ReturnDownloadMetaData(file.FileName, true));
      }

      return new FileDownloadReturnMessage(null,
                    new ReturnDownloadMetaData(null, false));
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
      throw new FaultException<IOException>(e);
   }
}
```

Client calling method:

```
 // Read buffer
 const int bufferSize = 65536;

 // Output buffer 
 Byte[] buffer = new Byte[bufferSize];
 int bytesRead;

 // Prepare download stream
 Stream donwloadStream;

 ReturnDownloadMetaData file = fileClient.DownloadFile(downloadMetaData, out donwloadStream);

 // If file server return valid file stream
 if (file.IsValid)
 {
    // Create a new temp document 
    using (FileStream outfile = new FileStream("C:\\#ComDocs_FileServer\\" + file.FileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
       // Write bytes from source into local file
       while ((bytesRead = donwloadStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
       {
          outfile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the maxReceievedMessageSize is how big the data is that the receiver is prepared to accept. In the code above, for download, the client is the receiver. You need to increase the maxReceievedMessageSize in the client as well (you don't appear to be doing this from the code you have shown)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

maxBufferSize ="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"

at both sender and receiver end.